# Importar fichero SQL desde Java

Tags: java, mysql, jfilechooser

Estoy tratando de **cargar un archivo .sql** en un servidor **localhost** mediante **Java**. El problema es que no me carga el fichero **.sql** pero sí me muestra el mensaje "Backup correcto".

**Utilidades**: Windows 10, Netbeans 8.2, JDK 1.8, Xampp/phpmyadmin

Clase **Conexiones** y método **conexion_a_BBDD** (testeado y probado - funciona correctamente):

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static Connection c = null;

    public static String getUsuario() {
       return usuario;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
       return password;
    }

    public static String getBBDD() {
       return bbdd;
    }

    /**
     * Conexión a BBDD.
     *
     * @param bbdd
     * @return
     */
    public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
            return c;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getStackTrace(), "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException n) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed! Se cerrará el programa...", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Abrir navegador de archivos JFileChooser**:

```
    private void button_seleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JFileChooser archivo = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter extension = new FileNameExtensionFilter("SQL", "sql");
        archivo.setFileFilter(extension);
        int se = archivo.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(se == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            String ruta = archivo.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            textfield_ubicacion.setText(ruta);
        }
    }
```

**Cargar el .sql**:

```
private void button_cargarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String ruta = textfield_ubicacion.getText();
    String backup = "";
    if(ruta.trim().length()!=0){
        try{
            backup = "mysqldump -u"+Conexiones.getUsuario()+" -p"+Conexiones.getPassword()+" "+Conexiones.getBBDD()+" < "+ruta+"";
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            r.exec(backup);
            System.out.println(r);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup importado correctamente");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Flujo del programa:**

1. Accedo al `JFileChooser` -> OK
2. Selecciono el fichero SQL y lo cargo en el `textfield_ubicacion` -> OK
3. Pulso el `button` Cargar me muestra "Backup importado correctamente" pero no me lo
   carga. En las `BBDD` de `phpmyadmin` no me aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tu archivo es un `.sql` o es un archivo comprimido? Y, el comando para restaurar es mysqldump

Comment: @A.Cedano Es un archivo .sql, sin comprimir.

Comment: El comando para restaurar es mysqldump, no mysql. [Revisa el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

Comment: @A.Cedano Acabo de probar con "mysqldump en lugar de mysql" y me ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: Revisa el MR (enlace anterior) y verifica que estás poniendo el comando correctamente. Si es posible imprime la cadena completa que mandas a ejecución y prueba en la consola, donde te dirá si tienes errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano He estado revisando el link pero realizando los comandos que indica "mysqldump" tampoco consigo cargar la bbdd .sql desde Java. Si imprimo el error, me da el siguiente resultado: "run:
java.lang.Runtime@6f099602"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124096/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-a-cedano).

Comment: @A.Cedano He modificado el comando como dice el link que adjuntaste y he imprimido la ruta que añado al textfield para saber si llega correctamente la ruta del fichero y la ruta es correcta. El fallo está en que no inserta correctamente el .sql

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124122/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html), los backups con formato `.sql` pueden ser restaurados de diferentes maneras, según hayas creado el archivo al momento de haber ejecutado `mysqldump`.

Dado que tu archivo ya contiene el `CREATE DATABASE` dentro y también el `USE laBaseDeDatos`  no tienes que ejecutar esos comandos previamente, sino que puedes pasar a ejecutar el comando de importanción directamente.

El comando podría escribirse perfectamente así:

```
backup = "mysqldump -u"+Conexiones.getUsuario()+
         " -p"+Conexiones.getPassword()+
         " "+Conexiones.getBBDD()+" < "+ruta+"";
```

Pero, hay una nota en el MR (al final del enlace citado más arriba) que dice lo siguiente:

> For Windows PowerShell users: Because the "`<`" character is reserved
> for future use in PowerShell, an alternative approach is required,
> such as using quotes `cmd.exe /c "mysql < dump.sql"`.
>
> ---
>
> Para usuarios de Windows PowerShell: debido a que el carácter "`<`"
> está reservado para uso futuro en PowerShell, se requiere un enfoque
> alternativo, como usar comillas `cmd.exe /c "mysql <dump.sql"`.

Puede que ese sea el motivo por el que tu código no está funcionando. Dado que quieres ejecutarlo desde el RunTime de Java, entonces la alternativa más segura es usar `source` (que sustituye al carácter `<`) para indicar donde se encuentra el archivo que quieres restaurar:

```
backup = "mysqldump -u"+Conexiones.getUsuario()+
         " -p"+Conexiones.getPassword()+
         " "+Conexiones.getBBDD()+" source "+ruta;
```